# Mule JSON - how to transform key value pairs to a list

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I have a json payload with the following format:

```
{"key":"value",
 "key:1":"value",
 "key:2","value",
 "junk key":"value",
 "part":"value",
 "part:1","value", 
 "part:2","value"...}
```

and want to transform it to:

```
{"1":{
   "key":"value",
   "part":"value"
   },
 "2": {
   "key":"value",
   "part":"value"
   },
 "3": {
   "key":"value",
   "part":"value"
   }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closet output I could get using Dataweave, just the formatting of removing additional curly braces could be done in the subsequent message processor using MEL or simple java code. Hope it helps!!

**Input JSON** 
{
   "key":"value1",
   "key:1":"value2",
   "key:2":"value3",
   "junk key":"value4",
   "part":"value5",
   "part:1":"value6",
   "part:2":"value7"
}

**Dataweave Logic:**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%var keyValues = payload mapObject {
    ('$$' : $)when ( '$$' matches /key(:\d)?/)
}
%var partValues = payload mapObject {
    ('$$' : $)when ( '$$' matches /part(:\d)?/)
}
%var zipValues = (keyValues zip partValues) map {
    '$$': {
        key: $[0],
        part: $[1]
    }
}
---
zipValues map {
    '$$' : $[0]
}
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "0": {
      "key": "value1",
      "part": "value5"
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "key": "value2",
      "part": "value6"
    }
  },
  {
    "2": {
      "key": "value3",
      "part": "value7"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You can strip the wrapper objects with {( )}, like so: {( zipValues map { ... } )}

Answer (score 0):

Senthil has a working solution already, but here's a general solution for any keys that contain a colon:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%function parseKeys(o) o pluck { 
    key: $$ replace /(\w+)(:\w+)?/ with $[1],
    group: $$ match {
        /(\w+):(\w+)/ -> $[2],
        default -> null
    },
    value: $
}
%function toNiceObject(tuples) {(tuples map {($.key): $.value})}
---
parseKeys(payload)
filter ($.group != null)
groupBy $.group
mapObject (
    '$$': toNiceObject($)
)
```

I thought it would be best to first break up the keys (the `parseKeys` function), producing an array of objects that have `key`, `group`, and `value` fields.  Then we can `filter` and `groupBy` the intermediate data structure, and turn it back into tuples for the result object at the end (`toNiceObject`).

The other thing to notice is the use of `pluck` and `match` to make `parseKeys` work. [pluck](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#pluck) takes an object and produces an array by applying the given function to each key value pair (tuple) in the object. [match](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-language-introduction#pattern-matching) lets us apply different transformations to a given input based on some criteria, in this case a regular expression.